# Is there an algorithm that tells the semantic similarity of two phrases

Tags: algorithm, nlp, semantics

input: phrase 1, phrase 2

output: semantic similarity value (between 0 and 1), or the probability these two phrases are talking about the same thing

Comment: WordNet Similarity for Java online demo was helpful in getting a feel for the different algorithms provided by WordNet: http://ws4jdemo.appspot.com

Comment: i am a new comer to NLP and was hesitating between graph random walk and word vector;  I am interested in your demo. can you please provide information? specially about the process of chinese language?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

---

You might want to check out this paper:

[Sentence similarity based on semantic nets and corpus statistics (PDF)](http://ants.iis.sinica.edu.tw/3BkMJ9lTeWXTSrrvNoKNFDxRm3zFwRR/55/Sentence%20Similarity%20Based%20on%20Semantic%20Nets%20and%20corpus%20statistics.pdf)

I've implemented the algorithm described. Our context was very general (effectively any two English sentences) and we found the approach taken was too slow and the results, while promising, not good enough (or likely to be so without considerable, extra, effort).

You don't give a lot of context so I can't necessarily recommend this but reading the paper could be useful for you in understanding how to tackle the problem.

Regards,

Matt.

Comment: I've implemented the algorithm too, it's not good enough but acceptable

Comment: I have read this paper and still confuse about the h parameter which indicate the depth of subsummer. Where is the highest subsummer which is used as the starting point to measure the depth of a certain word?

Answer (score 35):

There's a short and a long answer to this.

The short answer:

Use the [WordNet::Similarity Perl package](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WordNet-Similarity/). If Perl is not your language of choice, check the [WordNet project page](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) at Princeton, or google for a wrapper library.

The long answer:

Determining word similarity is a complicated issue, and research is still very hot in this area. To compute similarity, you need an appropriate represenation of the *meaning* of a word. But what would be a representation of the meaning of, say, 'chair'? In fact, what *is* the exact meaning of 'chair'? If you think long and hard about this, it will twist your mind, you will go slightly mad, and finally take up a research career in Philosophy or Computational Linguistics to find the truth™. Both philosophers and linguists have tried to come up with an answer for literally thousands of years, and there's no end in sight.

So, if you're interested in exploring this problem a little more in-depth, I highly recommend reading Chapter 20.7 in [Speech and Language Processing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131873210) by Jurafsky and Martin, some of which is available through [Google Books](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=fZmj5UNK8AQC&pg=PA379&lpg=PA379b&ots=LqQbZ7EJPG&sig=7VIRoXss0BNLv-B28FCPQgnqjVs&hl=en&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=1&ct=result#PPA658,M1). It gives a very good overview of the state-of-the-art of distributional methods, which use word co-occurrence statistics to define a measure for word similarity. You are not likely to find libraries implementing these, however.

Answer (score 9):

For anyone just coming at this, i would suggest taking a look at SEMILAR - http://www.semanticsimilarity.org/ . They implement a lot of the modern research methods for calculating word and sentence similarity. It is written in Java.

> SEMILAR API comes with various similarity methods based on Wordnet, Latent Semantic Analysis (LSA), Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA), BLEU, Meteor, Pointwise Mutual Information (PMI), Dependency based methods, optimized methods based on Quadratic Assignment, etc. And the similarity methods work in different granularities - word to word, sentence to sentence, or bigger texts.

Answer (score 8):

You might want to check into the [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) project at Princeton University. One possible approach to this would be to first run each phrase through a stop-word list (to remove "common" words such as "a", "to", "the", etc.) Then for each of the remaining words in each phrase, you could compute the semantic "similarity" between each of the words in the other phrase using a distance measure based on WordNet. The distance measure could be something like: the number of arcs you have to pass through in WordNet to get from word1 to word2.

Sorry this is pretty high-level. I've obviously never tried this. Just a quick thought.

Answer (score 6):

I would look into latent semantic indexing for this. I believe you can create something similar to a vector space search index but with semantically related terms being closer together i.e. having a smaller angle between them. If I learn more I will post here.

Comment: To amplify: get a representative (large) text corpus, decompose each document into bigrams ("terms"), make a matrix counting occurrence of terms (rows) in documents (columns), decompose the matrix, round/project/reduce dimensionality, use the result to make new predictions.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to dig up a 6 year old question, but as I just came across this post today, I'll throw in an answer in case anyone else is looking for something similar.

cortical.io has developed a process for calculating the semantic similarity of two expressions and they have a [demo of it up on their website](http://www.cortical.io/demos/similarity-explorer/). They offer a [free API providing access to the functionality](http://www.cortical.io/developers.html), so you can use it in your own application without having to implement the algorithm yourself.

Comment: Do you what API they use for their similarity viewer that you linked to (http://www.cortical.io/demos/similarity-explorer/)?  I assumed it was the '/compare' API (http://api.cortical.io/) but with the terms "long" and "length" I get a cosineSimilarity of 0.35 from the API and a similarity %age of 41% in the web interface.  Do you know what the difference is?

Comment: That demo is currently using a different version of the API with a different encoding Retina than the public API available at api.cortical.io, so the similarity scores will vary slightly.

Comment: ok thanks for that.  Can you just confirm to me though that 'cosineSimilarity' through the compare api is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Yes that demo is using the cosine similarity. That is just one of a few distance measurements returned by the cortical.io API, but in general cosine similarity is quite a good measurement. More info at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity

Answer (score 3):

One simple solution is to use the dot product of character n-gram vectors.  This is robust over ordering changes (which many edit distance metrics are not) and captures many issues around stemming.  It also prevents the AI-complete problem of full semantic understanding.

To compute the n-gram vector, just pick a value of n (say, 3), and hash every 3-word sequence in the phrase into a vector.  Normalize the vector to unit length, then take the dot product of different vectors to detect similarity.

This approach has been described in 
[J. Mitchell and M. Lapata, “Composition in Distributional Models of Semantics,” Cognitive Science, vol. 34, no. 8, pp. 1388–1429, Nov. 2010., DOI 10.1111/j.1551-6709.2010.01106.x](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1551-6709.2010.01106.x/abstract)

Comment: ... and hash every 3- character ? Did you mean 3-words?

Answer (score 2):

I would have a look at statistical techniques that take into consideration the probability of each word to appear within a sentence. This will allow you to give less importance to popular words such as 'and', 'or', 'the' and give more importance to words that appear less regurarly, and that are therefore a better discriminating factor. For example, if you have two sentences:

1) The smith-waterman algorithm gives you a similarity measure between two strings.
2) We have reviewed the smith-waterman algorithm and we found it to be good enough for our project.

The fact that the two sentences share the words "smith-waterman" and the words "algorithms" (which are not as common as 'and', 'or', etc.), will allow you to say that the two sentences might indeed be talking about the same topic.

Summarizing, I would suggest you have a look at:
 1) String similarity measures;
 2) Statistic methods;

Hope this helps.

Comment: Gia: the following strings are similar: (`I love you`, `I hate you`) but have opposite meanings. The following strings are dissimilar but have similar meanings: (`Thank you; the dinner was delicious!`, `You always cook a fine meal. Much appreciated.`) Using an uncommon word: (`An onomatopoeia is a word that imitates the sound of the thing it describes`, `Children and non-natives use onomatopoeia to describe things more than adult native speakers.`) are not saying the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Try [SimService](http://swoogle.umbc.edu/SimService/), which provides a service for computing top-n similar words and phrase similarity.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @user1803551, the gold standard for answers recommending an external program or library is to [explain precisely how they apply to the question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605), which has been done here.

Answer (score 1):

This requires your algorithm actually knows what your talking about. It can be done in some rudimentary form by just comparing words and looking for synonyms etc, but any sort of accurate result would require some form of intelligence.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://mkusner.github.io/publications/WMD.pdf This paper describes an algorithm called Word Mover distance that tries to uncover semantic similarity. It relies on the similarity scores as dictated by word2vec. Integrating this with GoogleNews-vectors-negative300 yields desirable results.