# How does Stack Overflow display similar questions when you type in a new q​uestion?

Tags: search, full-text-search, similarity

This is one of the things that Stack Overflow and the rest of the sites that run on this platform do very well. As soon as you try to create a new question, a little window is shown that shows other similar questions. How is this done? What technology can be used to achieve this? Lucene, Sphinx, ...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

StackOverflow (and StackExchange in general) [uses](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/3/3/stack-overflow-architecture-update-now-at-95-million-page-vi.html) Lucene.net for full-text search.

Might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891772/stackoverflow-related-questions-algorithm) as well.

Comment: Thanks, I guess the algorithm doesn't work that well since it didn't show that as a similar question hehe

Comment: It works great, but it's restricted by the keywords that you type in. If you (or others before you) are bad at choosing question titles, the search feature won't work all that well for you.