# Classifying text into different classes depending on similarity

Tags: nlp, nltk, computer-science, weka, svm

I am working on very large documents {NEWS + Articles} using modeling Natural Sentences into classes, please look at the following example:

```
1- The System enables a user to shut down the server remotely ==> class 1

2- The Application allows a customer to to close the machine online ==> (must be also) class 1 , why ?
```

because both sentences have many similar synonyms {System ~Application,enables ~ allows ,user ~ customer ,shut down ~ close,server ~ machine,remotely~online}
so I am  doing  classifier train    on some data depending on the similarity rules or synonyms of the words + stemming + may be (lemmatization) the most number of rules the most result we can get.

so the question what is the best strategy to configure/adjust the classifier to that ideas ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: check out: radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at this ??

[Is there an algorithm that tells the semantic similarity of two phrases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62328/is-there-an-algorithm-that-tells-the-semantic-similarity-of-two-phrases)

The most important is to determine similarity means. If you do that, choosing a classifier is the easy part of the task (ID3, C4.5, bag-of-words, naive bayes, etc.).